# .tolist in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to follow this code https://pythonforfinance.net/2018/02/08/stock-clusters-using-k-means-algorithm-in-python/ on a Conda environment with Python 3 on Linux Mint.

```
from numpy.random import rand
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as dr
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
sp500_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'
#read in the url and scrape ticker data
data_table = pd.read_html(sp500_url)
tickers = data_table[0][1:][0].tolist()
prices_list = []
for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        prices = dr.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo','01/01/2017')['Adj Close']
        prices = pd.DataFrame(prices)
        prices.columns = [ticker]
        prices_list.append(prices)
    except:
        pass
    prices_df = pd.concat(prices_list,axis=1)
prices_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
prices_df.head()
```

While I have succesfuly installed all required dependencies, I get the following Key Error that I have not been able to resolve:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-79802855cb59> in <module>
----> 1 tickers = data_table[0][1:][0].tolist()

~/miniconda3/envs/generic37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~/miniconda3/envs/generic37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Note that the CSV file loads ok. The code throws an error when I reach the `.tolist()` command.

Do you know the source of this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you already try printing data_table? Maybe its empty because there was an error getting the html of the page.

Comment: You access the columns of a dataframe, I suppose. However, there doesn't seem to be a `int(0)` column.

Comment: Yes, I can print the data_table, it looks fine.

Comment: @janus235 I just copy paste the code from the website and I assume that it works for him.

Comment: Can you show us printed data_table?

Comment: Try replaceing the line with `tickers = data_table[0].iloc[:, 0].tolist()`

Comment: @ChrisA what does this replacement exactly do? It seems to work.

Comment: `data_table[0]` indexes into the list `data_table`, takes the first dataframe, then `iloc[:, 0]` takes all rows, first column of the dataframe - returning a Series, then `.tolist` is a method on Series to convert to standard python `list`

Comment: @ChrisA last Q. Why did the previous code not work?

Comment: it's weird slicing - your slicing the dataframe from index `1:` (ie every row, from the 2nd to the last) , so index `0` (row 1) has been filtered out, then the next chained `[0]` is trying to return index 0.... so KeyError, because it doesn't exist